# T-SQL IF problemo

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, syntax-error

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getipmp]
@year varchar(4)
AS
BEGIN

select * from (

IF @year = ''
    select distinct carlinenm
    from [interchange].[dbo].[carline] 
    WHERE CarlineYear >= 1990
ELSE
    select distinct carlinenm
    from [interchange].[dbo].[carline] 
    WHERE CarlineYear = @year

UNION ALL

SELECT distinct cast(carlineyear as varchar(4)),'Y|' + rtrim(cast(carlineyear as varchar(4)))
from [interchange].[dbo].[carline]
WHERE carlineyear >= 1990

) U

END
```

SQL-Express is saying:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure getipmp, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure getipmp, Line 43 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

It refers to the "IF" at beginning and to the last ")" before the U.

Any idea what is wrong there?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the stupid title - Stackoverflow took me almost a half hour trying to post the question because it didn't like my titles... :(

Comment: `IF` isn't an expression, it can't appear inside a statement. it's a logical flow operator. `IF (X = y) BEGIN SELECT 1; END; ELSE BEGIN SELECT 2; END;`

Comment: Larnu - I don't think that add a couple BEGIN and END will solve the issue. Now I have the red underline all over the query!

Comment: No `BEGIN ... END` won't fix the problem that you have an `IF` statement in the middle of a `SELECT` statement. You missed the point of the comment. `SELECT * FROM IF @A = @B dbo.MyTable ELSE dbo.YourTable` Isn't valid syntax. It you have to be `IF @A = @B THEN SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable; ELSE SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldnt it be:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getipmp]
(
    @year varchar(4)
)
AS
BEGIN

    select  distinct carlinenm
    ,       null
    from [interchange].[dbo].[carline] 
    WHERE (CarlineYear >= 1990 AND @year = '') OR CarlineYear = @year

    UNION ALL

    SELECT distinct 
        cast(carlineyear as varchar(4))
    ,   'Y|' + rtrim(cast(carlineyear as varchar(4)))
    from [interchange].[dbo].[carline]
    WHERE carlineyear >= 1990
END
```